# Segue identifier name mark as use of undeclared type

Tags: ios, swift3, segue

I'm very new to ios development and I'm trying to learn how to pass data between ViewControllers.

```
@IBAction func load3rdScreenPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "PlaySongSegue", sender: "Hello")
}

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let destination = segue.destination as? PlaySongSegue {
        if let song = sender as? String {
            destination.selectedSong = song

        }
    }
}
```

On above code there's a error message saying "Use of undeclared type `PlaySongSegue`"

But I have declared this segue identifier. Please point me out what i'm doing wrong in this.

[image]

Comment: What is the class name (swift file) of the VC you're navigating to?

Comment: Note for line : if let destination = segue.destination as? **[YOUR DESTINATION VIEW CONTROLLER]**,which I assume in your case will be PlaySongViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`segue.destination` is of type `UIViewController`, so there you need to cast `segue.destination` to the `UIViewController` subclass that the ViewController you are segueing to has. Looking at your screenshot this seems to be `PlaySongViewController`.

"PlaySongSegue" is the identifier of the segue. This can be used if you have several segues from a single ViewController to check which ViewController you are segueing to. Checking the identifier is not needed for your use case, but I have added it to the code anyways, since you might need it later on.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "PlaySongSegue", let destination = segue.destination as? PlaySongViewController {
        if let song = sender as? String {
            destination.selectedSong = song

        }
    }
}
```